# ReactJS: Maximum update depth exceeded with localstorage

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a login page where the user is authenticating against my server. If the user is successfully authenticated then I set 2 local storage keys - one for `token` and another for `authtoken`.

The the user can navigate between pages of the app the checks the existence of those values without any problem.

When I log out, the logout button calls the following function:

```
const handleLogout = () => {
    logout();
    history.replace("/");
};
```

the `logout()` function simply clears the above mentioned values:

```
localStorage.removeItem("token");
localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
```

The problem is that upon logout the application throws the following exception:

```
Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

I initially thought the problem is with something in the login page component, but I rolled everything up on that component and further more I've created a blank new page to redirect to and the same exception result occured.

Only when I comment out the call to `logout()` the route replace is working without any issues (of course not deleting the values from localstorage).

Is localstorage affecting state in any way that I'm not expecting? What's going on?

**EDIT**

I found the place where the loop if happening. I have a Protected Route component that looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { isAuthenticated } from "../../services/api/auth";

function ProtectedRoute({
    component: Component,
    children: ChildComponent,
    ...rest
}) {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                if (isAuthenticated()) {
                    return (
                        (Component && <Component {...props} />) ||
                        ChildComponent
                    );
                } else {
                    return (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: "/",
                                state: { from: props.location },
                            }}
                        />
                    );
                }
            }}
        />
    );
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

When `logout()` is called and the `history.replace("/");` is taking place it's calling this component on behalf of my page (unmounting?) why is it rendering this page when the `"/"` page being redirected to is not using this component?

Comment: Can you share a more complete and comprehensive code example? What is rendered on the `"/"` path? What does it do when mounting? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, as mentioned above, even on a new completely blank react functional component it does the same. So I don’t believe “/“ is relevant.

Comment: It might not be the `"/"` route specifically, but from what you describe it sounds like after the redirect a new routed component is mounted/rendered and I'm guessing some auth check is happening. Maybe it's just a race condition. We can't help debug code we can't see though.

Comment: Please see edited section in question above

Comment: Is path `"/"` your "login" page? Can you share your router and routes configuration/code? I think your `ProtectedRoute` component could be tightened/cleaned up a bit, but don't see any overt issues there. It might just be that it's redirecting to that base route and what that route is rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my specific problem. But since I've learned how to create the protected route from an article online, this might be useful for others that might encounter this and don't understand why.

The issue was in the `ProtectedRoute` component. Each time a page is changed it is called (checked on an empty react app as well). And when it's calling the `render` inside the `Route` component, which then evaluates `isAuthenticated()`. Since authentication data is removed this is false and therefor falls to the `Redirect` component which again causes the `ProtectedRoute` to be re-rendered - and again and again - therefor - a loop.

To solve this, I've added a list to the component containing unprotected routes that should be ignored if auth is failed and they are the active route:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { isAuthenticated } from "../../services/api/auth";

function ProtectedRoute({
    component: Component,
    children: ChildComponent,
    ...rest
}) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const unProtectedPaths = ["/"];

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                if (isAuthenticated()) {
                    return (
                        (Component && <Component {...props} />) ||
                        ChildComponent
                    );
                } else if (!unProtectedPaths.includes(location.pathname)) {
                    return (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: "/",
                                state: { from: props.location },
                            }}
                        />
                    );
                }
            }}
        />
    );
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```